# It would help if review tools could have descriptions as well as ID's in links for dupe's

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, duplicate-questions, review, 10k-tools

I recently received the privilege for the 10k moderator tools and found the following a little awkward to work with. While reviewing flags, whenever an flag is raised for closing as a duplicate, it is in this format:

[image: exact duplicate of stackoverflow.com/questions/11264825]

However there is no semantic information in the link, it's just an ID. I have to actually go to the link to see what it is. Would it be possible for the flag review index list itself to show the friendly (human readable) title in the link rather than just the ID?

For example, instead of:

```
exact duplicate of stackoverflow.com/questions/1126825
```

it would be:

```
exact duplicate of stackoverflow.com/questions/11264825/having-issue-while-making-the-client-calls-persession-in-c-sharp-wcf
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure how much this would help. Seeing just the title of the possible duplicate isn't really helpful either. You still need to go view the post to see if the question is a duplicate or not. At least, I certainly hope people wouldn't be making judgement calls on flags like that without actually viewing **both** of the questions to evaluate their duplicateness. Not showing it in the flag reason is probably just a way of shortening it so it doesn't look terrible in the queue.

Even using your example. If given:

> [**Client async call to WCF service**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11234419/client-async-call-to-wcf-service) (1)
>   I have implemented a c# wcf service which has method s1 and method s2. method s1 is the main process that does the processing and method s2 is a secondary method that keeps track of the method s1 status based on two static int variables(total,current).
>   total ----> indicates the total number of tasks.
>   current-----> indicates the current task that is being processed.
>   I have also created 3...

and also given:

> exact duplicate of [stackoverflow.com/questions/11264825/having-issue-while-making-the-client-calls-persession-in-c-sharp-wcf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11264825)

I don't see how "*having-issue-while-making-the-client-calls-persession-in-c-sharp-wcf*" is at all useful in determining if the flag is valid. That text doesn't actually identify the "issue" they're having, only a general place where they're encountering the issue. A lot of duplicate questions are exactly like this: one question having a detailed title and the other having a poor, generalized title (which is probably why they didn't find the duplicate in the first place).